# MySQL error: operand should contain 1 column(s) on simple update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure in MySQL which should update a table named 'task' with a value depending on conditions. The problem is the following row

```
UPDATE task SET validity = 1 WHERE id = _task_id;
```

This query does nothing, although it works in this case:

```
UPDATE task SET validity = NULL WHERE id = _task_id;
```

The stored procedure is executed when called from PHP page, and I'm sure that all IN parameters are valid, since the other lines of the procedure are executed correctly.

Here's the definition of 'task' table:

```
  CREATE TABLE task(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  camp_id INT NOT NULL,
  heading VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  description VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  validity INT(1),
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT task_fk
  FOREIGN KEY(camp_id) REFERENCES work_campaign(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Stored procedure:

```
    DELIMITER //

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS define_task_result;
    CREATE PROCEDURE define_task_result(IN _task_id INT, IN count_answers INT)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE _camp_id INT;
      DECLARE _validity_threshold INT;
      DECLARE count_answer_options INT;
      DECLARE counter INT unsigned;
      DECLARE _option VARCHAR(100);
      DECLARE _percentage INT;
      DECLARE max_percentage INT;
      DECLARE selected_option_number INT;
      DECLARE check_max_number INT;


      SET _camp_id = (SELECT camp_id FROM task WHERE id = _task_id);
      SET _validity_threshold = (SELECT validity_threshold FROM work_campaign WHERE id = _camp_id);
      SET counter = 0;

      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS options_percentage;
      CREATE TABLE options_percentage (
       opt VARCHAR(100),
       percentage INT DEFAULT 0
      );

      INSERT INTO options_percentage(opt)
      SELECT answer_option FROM task_answers_options WHERE task_id = _task_id;

      SET count_answer_options = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM options_percentage);

      WHILE counter < count_answer_options DO
        SET _option = (SELECT opt FROM options_percentage LIMIT counter,1);
        SET selected_option_number = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_worker_answers WHERE answer = _option);
        SET _percentage = (selected_option_number / count_answers) * 100;
        UPDATE options_percentage SET percentage = _percentage WHERE opt = _option;
        SET counter = counter + 1;
      END WHILE;

  SET check_max_number = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = (SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage));

  IF check_max_number > 1 THEN
    UPDATE task SET validity = NULL WHERE id = _task_id;
  ELSE
    SET max_percentage = (SELECT percentage FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = (SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage LIMIT 1));

    IF max_percentage >= _validity_threshold THEN
      UPDATE task SET validity = 1 WHERE id = _task_id;
    ELSE
      UPDATE task SET validity = NULL WHERE id = _task_id;
    END IF;
  END IF;


    END //

    DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried to call the same query from command line, it gave me the following error - **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**. I really can't see the way to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You have a query call returning more than one value.

It is this one here. It is at the top of the `ELSE` statement that contains your 'problem line' from your original question.

```
SET max_percentage = (SELECT percentage FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = (SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage));
```

Explanation below

`SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage`

This is good, it will only return a single value.

`SELECT percentage FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = {scalar}`

This is not always valid. What happens when multiple `percentage` matches occur?

You can use a `TOP` in `SQL Server` to limit your results. Other RMDBs have similar functions that you can lookup. I believe the `MySQL` equivalent is `LIMIT` and it goes at the end of the `SELECT Statement`. Hope that helps.

In response to your question update 8/31

This is what you currently have
`(SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage LIMIT 1))`

It needs to become this 
`(SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage )LIMIT 1)`

Currently, you're `LIMIT`ing the 'good' query, not the one that has the issue.

So the full line with the change noted above would be this:

```
SET max_percentage = (SELECT percentage FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = (SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage) LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: I added LIMIT 1 to query but it seems to solve nothing.. I think the problem might be the structure of the table 'task'

Comment: Can you edit your question or comment with what you updated the `query` to?

Comment: yup yup see response in my answer above

Comment: the problem is, even if i try to update the 'validity' field directly, without any condition, mysql throws error 'ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: Is it continuing to do this even with my noted change to your question update?

Comment: yep.. i edited the query as SELECT percentage FROM options_percentage WHERE percentage = (SELECT MAX(percentage) FROM options_percentage) LIMIT 1. Changes nothing. Maybe I should add a default value to 'validity' column

Comment: Hmm, you could try to assign a value to the variable `max_percentage` using `select` syntax instead. That would look like `SELECT 'percentage' FROM options_percentage WHERE (...) LIMIT 1 INTO max_percentage`

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you may have a data issue where your query isn't returning anything. This would mean that there is no `percentage` that satisfies the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: I don't understand why the random update query executed from command line behaves this way = > mysql> UPDATE task SET validity = 1 WHERE id = 10;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
mysql> UPDATE task SET validity = NULL WHERE id = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0